# Highlighting current line in VS.NET Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, text-editor

Is there anyway to change the color of the current line (*that cursor is blinking*)?

I try to find such an option in "Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors" but couldn't find a color option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Highlight all occurrences of selected word](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) or [HighlightLine](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5c9fb156-bc4d-40a2-b976-5025fe905c26) 
from the [Visual Studio gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Assuming requirement for whole line highlight, above solution will highlight single words and their occurance in code-file

Comment: Thanks, it seems like there is no native option for it.